# Create Whitelist for MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, mysql-workbench

To deploy a database-bound application to R Studio Shiny, the following code is used:

```
DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                       dbname='database_name',
                       host='my IP',
                       username='username',
                       password='passcode')
```

When I write this code, I am getting an error. I need to allow Shiny IP addresses to fix the error. Reference:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217592507-How-do-I-give-my-application-on-shinyapps-io-access-to-my-remote-database-

It worked fine when I created a DB from [freesqldatabase.com](https://www.freesqldatabase.com) and deployed it to Shiny to test it out. In this case I need to add a few IPs to MySQL whitelist. How can I do that? I am using the MySQL Workbench on the MacBook.

Note: Firewall is closed in my PC.

Comment: a) "I am getting an error" is significantly less informative than "I am getting the following error: <your error message" b) You want to connect to a server you are running on your local macbook at home? You will probably have to configure your router to allow remote traffic to reach your local device, try searching for "nat <your router name>" or "portforward <your router name>". Note that most home routers will not have a whitelist (and if yours does, you can add this later). Also note that you need to enter the public internet address, not e.g. 192.168.xxx or 10.xxx into your shiny app.

Comment: "deploy to shiny" ... deploy where? There are several ways/places to deploy shiny, including shinyapps.io and publicly-hosted instances of shiny-server (free and licensed) and rstudio-connect (licensed). (BTW, the code you say to *"deploy a db-bound app"*, but that's to connect to a DB, not deploy it. Deploying is likely using `rsconnect::deployApp` or IDE-buttons.) I don't know what "Shiny IP addresses" means ... I suspect it is allow-listing IP addresses to the DB instance from the shiny server, where-ever that is. Where does the DB reside?